# Who or Whom in this sentence Subject/Object?

Tags: relative-pronouns, case, who-whom

I read many sources on the correct usage of **who** and **whom**, like this [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/1162/1416). From that answer, it seems that you can always use **who**, I didn't know that.

However I would like to know if in this sentence I could use **whom**.

> I would just use XX, but it is not me **who** is going to be using it.

A bit of context on this. I am building an app, and I am being requested to use something, lets call it YY, but I would much rather use XX. But since I am not going to be using the app, I am inclined to use YY as requested. And I was talking about the issue with another member of my team, when the sentence was produced.

I am not native English speaker, and I never did any sentence syntax analysis in English.
I am not sure if this sentence is properly written.

I think in this sentence It wouldn't be correct to use **whom**, because I think **who** is the subject of this sentence. But I get confused because I start saying "it is not me".

I am thinking that maybe this sentence is not grammatically correct and that is why I am having issues identifying whether to use **who** or **whom**.

Is this the right way to write this sentence?

Comment: No, you cannot always use *who*. *whomsoever the letter is concerned* - **who** will **not** fit here!

Comment: @MaulikV, I wasn't referring to whomsoever, I was referring to the section that says "Fortunately for the English learner, in modern informal English, you don't need to distinguish them. Who (as well as derived forms like whoever) can be used in all positions."

Comment: Okay, still - *whom this matter is concerned to* - *who* will not fit here again!

Comment: In that case, you'd want to go with "to whom this matter concerns", I think.

Comment: @MaulikV are you are referring to the quote that says "you don't need to distinguish them. Who (as well as derived forms like whoever) can be used in all positions"? I extracted that from this answer: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/1162/1416 . It is the accepted answer an has lots of votes, so I assumed it is correct.

Comment: @Dzyann I disagree if it says that! *whom is this matter concerned to* - cannot take **who**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let me reintroduce a simple rule. **Note** that in **most of the cases** this will work. Though some will come up with their detailed views denying this! Yes, that *subject-object* rule is concrete (in fact, they are called that way - *I* is a subject pronoun and *me* is an object pronoun) but this one is simpler for learners like you and me.

To avoid perplexity, place **yourself** in the sentence. If **I** fits, it'll take **who** and if **me** fits, it'll take **whom!**

> Who/Whom this matter is concerned to? - Apply that rule - The matter is concerned to **me**. So, it'll take **whom**. 
>   Who/Whom is at the door? - Apply that rule - **I** am at the door. So, it'll take **who.**

So, in your sentence - Apply that rule - **I** am not going to use and therefore **who**. Thus...

> I would just use XX, but it is not just me **who** is going to use it. (changed some words to make it better).

Comment: You can also substitute "he" or "him" rather than "I" or "me", with the additional helpful tip that if you can use hi*M*, you can use who*M*.

Comment: @Roger yes yes! But then when it comes to *she*, he'll be confused! *I* remains *I* in any gender case! haha... anyway thanks. Oh yes, I got it... that's nice. +1

Comment: Well I like the subject-object rule. Just in this sentence I got lost on how to identify them, my first impression is that who is the subject, but as I said I have never done syntax analysis in English, and some cases are more complex than others. Thanks for the explanation!