# Who/whom confusion

Tags: relative-pronouns, case, who-whom

In this sentence "whom" is correct, but I think "who" is also correct. I need some grammatical explanation.

> John was crying for **who**/**whom** he lost.

**Context** - John lost his best friend in an accident.

My explanation -

John was crying for [his friend]

John was crying for [him]

John was crying for [who he lost]

The clause "who/whom he lost" will come down to "him". That "for" before the clause "who/whom he lost" does not attached to "for whom".

Am I right?

Comment: *The clause "who/whom he lost" will come down to "him". That "for" before the clause "who/whom he lost" does not attached to "for whom". Am I right?* <== I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to say here. :( . . . In any case, your example would probably be unacceptable in today's English, as neither "who" nor "whom" would be acceptable there. Your example seems to be treating the "who/whom" as a pronoun for a fused-relative, but "who/whom" normally cannot be used for a fused-relative unless it is a "free choice" construction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's review.  What you are trying to express is:

> John lost his friend.  John was crying for his friend.

Of course, such repetition is undesirable, so English has a tool you can use, called a [relative-pronoun](/questions/tagged/relative-pronoun).  Relative pronouns include *who*, *whom*, *that*, and *which*.  Of those choices, *who* and *whom* can be used to refer to people.  *Who* is used for subjects; *whom* is used for objects.

You probably know all that already, but just need advice in applying the rules.

The pronoun you want is the one in the **objective case (*whom*)**, because John lost his friend.  (Using the subjective case pronoun *who* would mean that the friend lost John, which is not what you want.)

Remember, also, that relative pronouns help you refer to a noun that would otherwise be repeated.  Relative pronouns don't stand alone.  The correct sentence should be:

> John was crying for **the friend whom he lost.**

---

That said, even native English speakers often fail to distinguish between subjective and objective cases correctly.  Therefore, you have to be careful about parroting patterns that you see and hear, as you may be copying incorrect examples.  On the other hand, you are also unlikely to be stigmatized for choosing the wrong case in everyday speech.

Comment: John was crying for the friend whom he lost. This example is fine. But what about my sentence - John was crying for who/whom he lost.? Who or whom? or Both?

Comment: _John was crying for who he lost_ is incorrect.  _John was crying for whom he lost_ gets the case right, but is still incorrect, since the antecedent needs to be present.

Answer (score 0):

*Who* is the subjective case. Use *who* when it replaces "I", "he", "she", etc.

*Whom* is the objective case. Use *whom* when it replaces "me", "him", "her", etc.

That said, in current American usage, anyway, many speakers use *who* for both the subjective and objective, and don't use *whom* at all.

Answer (score 0):

I consider that you are aware of the [general rules specified here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-can-one-differentiate-between-who-and-whom) or at least have gone through them. This way, I won't mention *subject/object* thing in this answer. But will provide you with what *I think.*

It seems, over the period of time, the subtlety of *who* and *whom* is settling down. I have read and heard many natives using *who* where I thought *whom* fitted better. When asked, they said the same what I said in the beginning. For instance, *"I wondered who she was talking to"* goes okay without being noticed. However, using *who/whom* both is okay in some cases and not all. *To whom it may concern* cannot be *To who it may concern.*

Your example seems to be one of those cases wherein *who/whom* both ***looks*** fine. In my humble opinion, if the grammar rule you know does not help, use your instinct.

Comment: But in my sentence there comes "for whom" part, we can't say "for who" there. But I think in this particular sentence "for who" is fine because "for" is not part of the clause "who/whom he lost". Am I right?

Comment: If you ask me, I'd certainly use *whom* because of the simple rule I learned - "John was crying for ***him"***. We use *..for who...* in construction like.. *Loving god for who he is.* :)