# Should I use "who" or "whom" in the following sentence?

Tags: difference, relative-pronouns, who-whom

Example:

> Someone wants me dead? I can't think of who/whom.

Should I use who or whom? Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one differentiate between "who" and "whom"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-can-one-differentiate-between-who-and-whom)

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate: it involves the role played by *who* in an ellipted relative clause, which supersedes its apparent role as object of the preposition *of*, and that is not addressed in the linked question.

Comment: +1, as I think this is an interesting question, especially for a weekend!

Comment: "I  have no idea who ( wants me dead)" would be much clearer. At first I didn't understand "I can't think of who/whom"  at all.

Comment: I agree that this is a really interesting question.  Note that unlike with most pronouns, where the accusative form is the default, in the case of *who(m)*, [the default form is *who*, used when the conditions for *whom* are not satisfied.](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004084.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Someone wants me dead? I can't think of who/whom.

This is an interesting sentence. At first glance you would think that *whom* is called for, because it is the object of the preposition *of*.

In fact it is **not** the object of the preposition. The object in the example is the fused relative clause *who wants me dead*, which has been reduced to *who* by ellipsis. In that clause *who* represents the subject; so nominative *who* is the correct form.

> Somebody wants me dead, I can't think of **who** <s>wants me dead</s>.

It should be pointed out, however, that idiomatically we would not use the preposition here. In this sort of context *think of X* has approximately the sense "remember X, call X to mind". What's wanted here is bare *think*, which has what appears to be the desired sense *imagine, conceive*.

> Somebody wants me dead, I can't think who.

It makes no difference to the use of *who/whom*, since *who* still acts as subject.

Comment: In *"I can't think of [anyone who would want me dead]"*, wouldn't the expression "anyone who would want me dead" be functioning as the complement of the preposition "of"? So, why wouldn't the "who" in the OP's original example, in which that "who" happens to be sitting in that corresponding spot, not also be considered to be functioning as the complement of the preposition "of"? . . . Also, perhaps the OP's example could be considered by some to correspond to *"I can't think of [whom that could be]"*? Just wondering here. :)

Comment: @F.E. In your first example, *anyone* is the object of *of* (and would "properly" be cast in the objective case: *I cannot think of him who wants me dead*); the relative clause now modifies that object and is no longer the object of *of* any more than an adjective fulfilling the same role would be. Your second example I think crosses register boundaries: a register which would accept *That could be him* will discard *whom*, while a register which employs *whom* would also demand *That could be he*. . . .

Comment: There are no doubt people who sit on the fence--which to my mind is a recipe for annoying **all** your audience instead of just half of it.

Comment: But in the first example, wouldn't the whole expression *"anyone who would want me dead"* be considered to be the object of the preposition? Similar to *"I can't think of [any boy who would want me dead]"*? The whole NP would be the object, wouldn't it?

Comment: @F.E. Yes; but only the head (if anything) declines as object, not its modifiers.

Comment: To be more specific, *whom* is typically called for as the object of a **fronted** preposition.

Answer (score 0):

**Prepositions in relative clauses**

1. When a relative clause includes a preposition, we can often choose whether to put it at the beginning or at the end. The latter is more common and more informal.

*That's the man **from whom we bought our car**.*

*That's the man **(who/that) we bought our car from**.*

2. However, when the preposition is part of a phrasal verb, it always stays with the verb.

*He adopted three children, **whom he looked after well**.*

3. Multi-word prepositional phrases can go at the beginning or end, but we don't separate the words.

*We saw a café, **in front of which sat several diners.***

*We passed a café, **which several diners sat in front of**.*

4. We can't put a preposition at the beginning when the relative pronoun is the subject of the following verb.

*I bought a house **which hadn't been lived in for years**.*

5. The relative pronoun may form part of a noun phrase such as *some of which, many of whom, the first of which* or an adverbial phrase like *at which point, for which reason, in which case.*

*I have three brothers, **the youngest of whom is five**.*

*He recorder more than fifty songs, **many of which became hits**.*

*The host fell asleep, **at which point we left**.*