# Which pronoun do I use: who/whom/that?

Tags: relative-pronouns, who-whom

> - I know the girl who/whom/that you are talking to.
> - It was the girl who/whom/that her mother punished for stealing money.

In these two sentences,which relative pronoun is suitable?

Comment: The first sentence is a prize winner: **I know the girl who you are talking to.** In a single sentence, you raise the blood pressure of proponents of two separate _"rules!"_ In either sentence, though, you can use any of them.

Comment: With personal antecedents, there is slight preference for "that" when it is not the subject of the relative clause, as in your examples. But it is only a preference, not a hard-and-fast rule. One advantage, though, of using "that" is that it avoids having to make the choice between formal "whom" and informal "who". But all three are perfectly grammatical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one differentiate between "who" and "whom"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-can-one-differentiate-between-who-and-whom)

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: personal pronouns like *who* and *whom* have case form. The case form for *who* is the nominative case (often the subject of a sentence); the case form for *whom* is the objective case, usually a direct object.

CORRECT: I know the girl **whom** you are talking to.

The relative pronoun "*whom*" is in the objective case. This means it acts not a subject, for example, but as an object. *Who* is the other case, the nominative case; it's the one you would use as a subject the sentence. The rule is that the object of a preposition "*to*" in a prepositional phrase is in the objective case: *whom*.

I know the girl. You are talking **to whom**

---

CORRECT: It was the girl **whom** her mother punished for stealing money.

For this one, we'll remove the main clause: *It was the girl*. [this is the main clause; it's and independent clause, which means it can stand on it's own as a sentence.

That leaves the dependent clause: *who/whom/that* *her mother punished for stealing money* [If we take out the relative pronouns, we can see if we have a subject and a verb: her mother punished for stealing. There's the verb--*punished* Now where's the subject? *mother*. But something is missing. Who? or What? did the mother punish? The girl. The girl is the direct object [she receives the action of the verb] of the verb "punished" and so since "girl" is in the main clause, her antecedent (the word the pronoun stands for), as a direct object, it needs to be in the objective case for the personal pronoun "**who**" which, if you recall in the first sentence is "**whom**" so....

"...her mother punished **whom** for stealing the money."

**Which, that, who** Remember the relative pronoun *who* refers to people only; *which* refers to things only; *that* refers to either people or things.—John E. Warriner. Warriner’s English Grammar and Composition. Third Course. Liberty Edition. Orlando, Florida: Harcourt, Brace, and Jovanovich. 1986. 270. But, as you see, *who* strictly refers to people. It's your choice.

Alternative:

CORRECT: I know the girl **that** you are talking to.

CORRECT: It was the girl **that** her mother punished for stealing money.