# Relative pronoun whom, who

Tags: relative-pronouns, grammar-myths, case

> 1. When you speak to him remember **to whom** you are speaking.
> 2. When you speak to him remember **who** you are speaking to.
> 3. When you speak to him remember **whom** you are speaking to.

What is the difference among these three? If any.

Answer (score 2):

### Use "whom" when it's the object of the sentence

> To **whom** should I send the letter?
>
> Send it to **whom**?
>
> **Whom** should we send?

"Whom" and "to whom" are the same thing. The "to" is just the preposition included with the pronoun.

### Use "who" in all other circumstances

> **Who** knows?
>
> We know **who** has the answer.

### English speakers ignore this distinction in dialogue ALL the time.

In fact, you are unlikely to hear/read "whom" outside of formal writing.

Comment: Use **whom** also for the INDIRECT OBJECT...to whom, for whom, in whom, from whom....etc

Comment: Reversed my negative vote accordingly although I think that your answer could be a bit more enlightening about WHO as subject as well as WHOM as direct/indirect object. And then there are always killers like:**The word "whom" is a pronoun.**

Answer (score 1):

All 3 of them mean the same thing. They differ only in formality, correctness of grammar, and evident education level of the speaker (or writer).

> When you speak to him remember to whom you are speaking.

follows all the rules of English grammar and is consequently the most formal and educated-sounding.

> When you speak to him remember whom you are speaking to.

has the correct pronoun case (whom), but breaks a lesser (?) grammar rule by separating "to" from "whom" and sticking the preposition at the end of the sentence. Some people claim this is an error, but I have heard others disagree. In any case, this sentence sounds more casual and slightly less "professorial".

> When you speak to him remember who you are speaking to.

is the one I would be most used to hearing in every day (US) English. Strictly speaking, I guess it is incorrect, as it uses "who" (nominative case) as the *object* of the preposition "to", but it is very commonly spoken and written, and it sounds normal, idiomatic, and informal.

Comment: No English authority any longer regards final or **stranded prepositions** as incorrect. The following article explains why they were once disapproved of (note the final **of**) :   https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/11/28/grammar-myths-prepositions/

Comment: Yeah, *When you speak to him remember who you're speaking to* is perfectly grammatical and appropriate in neutral/informal style. There's nothing "strictly speaking" or "technically" or "actually" or "kind of" incorrect about it. Don't make the mistake of conflating register and grammaticality. *When you speak to him, remember to whom you are speaking* isn't any more correct than the alternative above. The latter is merely formal, and would come across as stilted in most situations (other than formal ones, obviously). For more information see [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/1162/3395).