# "Who" or "Whom"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, who-whom

Please have a look on the following examples:

> 1-1- **Who** does he **look like**? 
>   1-2- **Who** does he **resemble**? 
>   1-3- **Whom** does he **look like**? 
>   1-4- **Whom** does he **resemble**?

As far as I know, for “he”’ or “’she,” we use "who" and for “him” or “her,” use "whom".

Consequently, we say:

- He **looks like me** (not "I"). [Therefore, we must be able to use "whom" not "who"!]
- He **resembles me** (not "I").[Therefore, we must be able to use "whom" not "who"!]

But Ngram shows somwthing else! Please have a look on the folloing link:
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whom+does+he+look+like%2Cwhom+does+he+resemble%2Cwho+does+he+look+like%2Cwho+does+he+resemble&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwhom%20does%20he%20resemble%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWhom%20does%20he%20resemble%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwhom%20does%20he%20resemble%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwho%20does%20he%20look%20like%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BWho%20does%20he%20look%20like%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwho%20does%20he%20look%20like%3B%2Cc0

The same goes for the following examples of mine:

> 2-1- **Who** is her demeanor like the most? 
>   2-2- **Who** is her demeanor similar to the most? 
>   2-3- **Whom** is her demeanor like the most? 
>   2-4- **Whom** is her demeanor similar to the most?

I have no any idea which one is correct and which one is incorrect?

I would appresiate it if you could help me to figure it out!

Comment: And none of the answers here help? https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/1162/

Comment: None of your 2.X solutions are idiomatic.  See solutions 2-5 and 2-6 in the answer below for who you should be saying it. Where you've gone wrong is forgetting that just as personal pronouns still have a genitive case inflection, so too does *who/whom/whose*.

Comment: I find it easier to remember ***he / him*** (same final consonant as ***who / whom***), but mostly we don't bother with ***whom*** at all these days, so it's not important. All your NGram link shows is that ***to resemble*** has been supplanted by ***to look like***, so of course the much-declined *older* version reflects a distinction that's largely ignored today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct about examples 1-1 through 1-4 - *whom* is the "correct" word, though in modern usage, *who* is usually used when *whom* would be appropriate. "Whom does he look like?" would probably sound affected or overly formal to a modern audience. As ColleenV points out, this question has been asked before, and Mechanical snail has a very good answer here: [How can one differentiate between "who" and "whom"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-can-one-differentiate-between-who-and-whom/1162#1162)

I also want to address examples 2-1 through 2-4. These questions all sound slightly "off". A demeanor is not a person, so you can not talk about one with the word "who". You can rephrase them as follows:

> 2-5- Whose demeanor is hers most like?
>
> 2-6- Whose demeanor is hers most similar to?

*Hers* is substituted for *her demeanor*. You want to know *which person's* demeanor is most like "hers" (whoever "she" is), so you should use the possessive pronoun *whose*.

That being said, I still think these "corrected" sentences sound kind of formal and awkward. You could probably get away with asking just:

> 2-7- Who is she most like?
>
> 2-8- Who is she most similar to?

Or to be more clear that you are talking about someone's *demeanor*, which I think is basically equivalent to *attitude*:

> 2-9- Who is she most like, attitude-wise?
>
> 2-10- Who is she most similar to, attitude-wise?

Comment: Thank you very much Mixolydian, but please let me know as per your statements, saying 2-7 & 2-8 using "whom" would be just formal, but it would work properly in written English only or when someone is giving a speech. Right?

Comment: @A-friend yes, using *whom* would be grammatically correct in examples 2-7 and 2-8 (As a statement: “She is most like (him/her)”- the part in parentheses is an object, not a subject). It would just sound more formal than using *who*. In writing or in a formal speech, yes, *whom* would sound more natural than in casual speech.