# Can l use whom instead of who in my example?

Tags: grammar, tense, clauses

Who the nominee will be has not been officially declared yet.

Note : as far as l know we can use "whom" providing  that we us it in object position in noun clause .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one differentiate between "who" and "whom"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-can-one-differentiate-between-who-and-whom)

Comment: Try substituting in a different pronoun like "he/him" and see which fits.  Is it *"**He** will be ..."* or *"**Him** will be ..."*?

Comment: Thank you Andrew  you  made it clear too

Answer (score 1):

In strict formal grammeer, if "whom" is correct, "who" is not. In current informal, and even much formal usage, "who" is used for both subject and object, and "whom" is never used.  I suspect that in 100 years "whom" will be listed in dictionaries as obsolete. But it isn't obsolete at this time.

If you want a way to determine when "whom" is formally proper, see if "he" or "him" can be placed in roughly the same place in a modified statement. If "he" fits, use "who". If "him" fits "whom" is probably technically proper. Another way to tell: if the person is **doing** the action, use who; if the person is **being acted on**, "whom" might be proper. These should give the same result.

In the example sentence:

> **Who** the nominee will be has not been officially declared yet.

"who" is proper" and "whom" would not be.

Consider that

> He will be the nominee.

properly uses "he".

However, one could write:

> We don't yet know **to whom** the nomination will be given.

When "whom" is used at all, it is often used directly following "to", as an object.

Comment: Thank you David you really made it clear

Answer (score 1):

> [*Who the nominee will be*] has not been officially declared yet.*

The simple answer is that when fronted "who" is a predicative complement, as it is here, it is always nominative; thus "who", not accusative "whom", is correct.